# Picture not showing up

Tags: html, css

As the title says I'm having problems with a picture. I've set the size and linked it to a separate folder correctly. What could be the issue?

I have no trouble with the "Header" background.

```
#logo{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: url(bilder/GC-logo.psd);
}

Header{
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(bilder/sweden-853150.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.logo{
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 260px;
    width:260px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}

    <Header>
        <div class="logo">
            <img id="logo" />
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">asdasdasd</a></li>
                <li><a href="">asdasdd</a></li>
                <li><a href="">zxczxczxc</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Hem</a></li>
        </nav>
        <div class="container" id="easy_nav">
            <div class="centered-text">
                <a href="index.map.html"><h2>something</h2></a>
                <a href="#"><h2>something</h2></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Logo image is not showing because your trying to use a PSD file.

Open the PSD in Photoshop and click File -> Save for web.

This will allow you to export the image as a jpg or png. Click save and make sure the exported image is in your bilder folder and change the css for the logo background to use the new image.

Comment: The newest Photoshop versions have [***dropped Save For Web***](http://blogs.adobe.com/crawlspace/2015/06/save-for-web-in-photoshop-cc-2015.html). It's no longer available under the *File* menu. Photoshop has upgraded the feature to something they call [***Adobe Generator***](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html). Although no longer supported, you can still access *Save For Web* under File -> Export -> Save for Web (legacy), but this probably won't last long.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe `.psd` files are supported for display using CSS. You can convert it to a different file format or try something like this:

http://thesiteslinger.com/blog/tutorial-how-to-code-your-psd-into-a-html-css-layout/